# Meaning of product with bar (\Gemini-symbol)

Tags: notation

In chapter IV, paragraph 2 of Neukirch's *Class Field Theory* he writes

> The adeles form a ring, denoted by $$\mathbb{A}_K = \prod_\mathfrak{p} K_\mathfrak{p}$$ where addition and multiplication is defined componentwise.

Except, he doesn't write $\prod$ but something like [image: this picture], i.e. a product sign with a bar underneath it. I can't figure out what he means by this.

Edit: Detexify tells me that the symbol is \Gemini in $\LaTeX$, which might help someone. Personally, if I had to guess it seems to be related to taking only elements with *finitely* many non-trivial factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found him using the same symbol in other books (*Algebraic Number Theory*) where he explains the use as the **[restricted direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_product)**.